# How change output jar name in gradle

Tags: gradle

How can I change the name of the output file jar using `Gradle`?

I want it to be called a super_jar.jar.

Using `Maven` I will be write in `pom.xml`:

```
<name>super_jar</name>
```

And it's all!
Using `Gradle`, I do not understand how to do this. I can not find anything through Google. Why is it so difficult?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

archiveName 'abc.jar' in your jar configuration is forcing the name to be 'abc.jar'. The default format for the jar name is ${baseName}-${appendix}-${version}-${classifier}.${extension}, where baseName is the name of your project and version is the version of the project. If you remove the archiveName line in your configuration you'll have the format you're after. If you want the name of the archive to be different from the project name set the baseName instead, e.g.

```
jar {
    manifest{
        attributes ("Fw-Version" : "2.50.00", "${parent.manifestSectionName}")
    }
    baseName 'abc'
}
```

See https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar:archiveName for more info on configuring the jar task.

Comment: Why When I added jar {
 baseName 'superjar'
} In Output I have superjar-1.0.0.jar?